# SQL to criteria using restrictions and projections

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Can anybody help me in writing the below SQL with hibernate criteria.

```
Select * 
rom cart c
where c.sno = '00001234a'
  and c.createdtime = (
    select max(c.createdtime)
    from cart c
    where c.sno='00001234a'
  )
```

I tried the below snippet.
But it is returning `timestamp(createdtime)` instead of cart object.

```
Criteria cr=session.createCriteria(cart.class,'ct');
cr.add(Restrictions.eq('ct.sno','00001234a'));
cr.setProjection(Projection.max(ct.createdtime));
List li=cr.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided code example is the same as

> select max(c.createdtime) from cart c where c.sno='00001234a'

To handle query that you provided you can use two requests and build "and c.createdtime" restriction basing on the results of the first query.
Or to use [createQuery](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm) method to build more complex query.